# javascript ajax post/get from one html-javascript to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am developing my first website. At this time i am generating a new html design that would be a ticket.
From my main page, i will load this html when the user clicks the "See ticket" button. This html has a table which is filled on document.ready with javascript. The data used is a JSON created in the main page.

I coded a working solution using localStorage. The problem is that the next step is to convert that HTML website to PDF and the software i am using does not work properly with localStorage, so i need to pass the JSON from main page to the ticket page. I can't neither use URL encoding cause string could be sometimes longer than 2000 characters and it is not productive.

So i thought that maybe i could do and $.get call from the ticket.html to index.html and get the needed JSON. Is this approach correct, or is there any better solution?

Regards

Comment: question is quite confusing since JSON is rarely delivered from `.html` file extension and is more commonly sent from extension associated to whatever server side language your server runs

Comment: well, i capture it using javascript associated to the html, which it does deal perfect with JSONs..

Comment: the point is you probably need to `post` your data to a server script which can be done using `$.ajax`

Comment: in that case i would need to store that JSON in a database and then $.get it from ticket.html..isn't there an easier solution to pass this JSON between clientside htmls/javascripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested earlier comments, you need to use serverside code to accept `post` params and you need to do a `ajax` post to send the data. This is very good approach. I have one more idea for implementing this.

Let say you open `ticket.html` in a `window.open`. And have a JS function ( say `GetValue`) in `index.html`, that returns `JSON` . So you need to get `JSON` in `ticket.html`.

You need to define a JS function in ticket.html , using `windown.opener.GetValue()` , you can get `JSON` value.

Hope, i am in same direction, which you need. If not, please clarify.

Other way, would be use `iFrame` and use message communication to pass large data between them, you are interested in this, please read this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: Thanks.i'll try this later on and i'll tell you.